# How to change the value of a variable stored in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

Variables can be stored into arrays, as such.

```
var x = 4,
    y = 8,
    z = 15,

var someArray = [x, y, z];
```

How can I change the value of a variable by referencing it through the array?

If I do the following, I get an undesired result.

```
//change value of y to 80.

someArray[1] = 80;
```

Rather than changing y's value to 80, the code replaces the second item in the array with the integer 80. My array would now be [x, 80, z]

I know I can change y's value explicitly and update the array...

```
y = 80;
someArray = [x, y, z];
someArray[1]; //80
```

But in a situation where I don't explicitly know the specific variable name in that array's position, I want to use the array to change it's value. How do I do this? My concept of arrays might be wrong. Am I confusing Objects with Arrays?
Thank you for any help and correction you can give me.

Comment: There isn't a reference back to the variable.

Comment: Arrays don't store variables. The array only does store the *value* of the variable which you assigned it. If you have set `someArray[1] = 80`, `y` didn't change. To get the value back in the variable, you will need to do `y = someArray[1]`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the correction. This helps me understand arrays better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var x = {val: 1},
    y = { val: 2 },
    z = { val: 3 },
    ary = [ x, y, z ];
// console.log(ary[0]) will put { val: 1 }
x.val = 4;
// console.log(ary[0]) will put { val: 4 }
```

This is because primitive values (numbers/strings) are passed by value. Once used, there is no reference to the value from the variable. However, objects are passed by reference, so theis connection is maintained. See also the best article I've seen on this issue: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Comment: My main concern was being able to refer to, or manipulate, a variable without me knowing what it was. So being able to work with x by using ary[0].val as a benefit of the object notation is perfect. Thank you for your code which led to me to my answer, and thanks for the good article.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the array is not storing the variables, rather the values of the variables, but if you wanted to simulate this, you could use multidimensional arrays or objects, as shown below:

```
var x = 4,y = 8,z = 15;

var someArray = {'x':x, 'y':y, 'z':z};
```

You'll then be able to access the values via dot notation or bracket notation, for example to get the value for x:

```
alert(someArray.x);
```